# Local extrema for non-constant polynomials

Tags: polynomials

> For a given real polynomial
>   $$p(x)=a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2+\dots +a_nx^n,\quad\text{with $a_0=0$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$},$$
>   is there any proof that all local extrema will always lie between two roots of $p(x)=0$?

I was messing around with some visualizations and tried to proof it using derivatives but could not solve it. Internet search wasn't helpful either.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not true, as the answer below gives an excellent counterexample. However, it _is_ true that between any two roots there is at least one local extremum, which is _almost_ the same thing, but not quite.

Comment: Thank you. The fact that I was asking for the case without constant term $a_0=0$ was somehow removed from my original question. Does that leave other counterexamples?

Answer (score 2):

That is not true. Take for example 
$$p(x)=6\int_0^x (t-1)(t-2)dt=2x^3-9x^2+12x$$
It has local extrema at $1$, and at $2$ but $p$ has just one root, that is $0$.

However, by [Gauss-Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem), for any non-constant polynomial $p$, all zeros of a $p'$ (the derivative is zero at local extrema) belong to the convex hull in the complex plane of the set of complex zeros of $p$.

Comment: Thanks, but I was specifically asking for the case where there is no constant term. (that was somehow edited out from my question)

Comment: @SaremSeitz: why this remark ? This is addressed in the answer.

Comment: Wow, that second paragraph was a surprising turn!

Comment: @Robert Z: Thanks, that was enlightening.